# How do I reimplement valueof on enumeration

Tags: java, enums

I need to re-implement the enum.valueof method of a few of my enumerations so they no longer throw exceptions, instead they simply return null if a value doesn't exist in the enumeration.

I'm trying the basic

```
@Override
    public static <T extends Enum<T>> T valueOf(Class<T> enumType,
            String name){
```

but it's not working, saying I need to override or implement a super type.

I can come up with a super class I guess, but I'm just not sure how to put this together.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can't. You'll have to define another, different method. The valueOf method is automatically generated by the compiler.

```
public static MyEnum permissiveValueOf(String name) {
    for (MyEnum e : values()) {
        if (e.name().equals(name)) {
            return e;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: yea, i guess im going to have to do it this way.  just was hoping i wouldn't have to change so much.   thanks

Comment: Yeah not sure why Java doesn't allow this.. overridding 'valueOf' would make a lot more sense than implementing your own and having clients of your enum need to learn your convention..

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think your method implementation actually requires the enum to have an additional `getName()` method. I think you should really be using the built-in `name()` to get the actual name of the enum.

Comment: @schneida indeed. Code changed.

Comment: `O(n)`. tsk-tsk.

Answer (score 11):

Use Apache Commons Lang:

```
MyEnum myEnum = EnumUtils.getEnum(MyEnum.class, "MY_ENUM_VALUE");
```

Quote from the [Javadoc for EnumUtils.getEnum](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/EnumUtils.html#getEnum%28java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String%29):

> **Gets the enum for the class, returning null if not found.**
>
> This method differs from Enum.valueOf(java.lang.Class,
>   java.lang.String) in that it does not throw an exception for an
>   invalid enum name.

Comment: Nice answer. That's bad we need additional libraries to behave Java as we would like to...

Answer (score 2):

Is it absolutely necessary that the method is called `valueOf` like the method that enums have automatically? In the project that I'm currently working on we have similar methods, but we call them differently; for example, `forName`:

```
public static ESomeEnum forName(String name) {
    for (ESomeEnum e : ESomeEnum.values()) {
        if (e.name().equals(name)) {
            return e;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: I wanted to call it valueOf because its referenced in dozens of other classes that are part of XML binding.  If I could override the valueof, then I didn't have to change my bindings at all, they would use my method by default.  But, if I were forced to create a new method, I would have to update those dozens of bindings.  Which is what I ended up having to do.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to override valueOf. Here's what I did:

I had to "parse" some strings to enums and they didn't match with their declaration names, so I did a sort of reimplementation of `valueOf(String name)`.

```
public enum Command {
    DIR("DIR"),
    PUT("PUT"),
    GET("GET"),
    OK("OK"),
    ERROR("ERROR"),
    READY("READY"),
    FIN("#FIN#");

    private String name;

    private Command(final String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the desired Enum or throws an exception
     * @param commandName - String with the name contained by the Enum that you want
     * @return Command
     */
    public static Command getEnum(String commandName){
        // if the string is "#FIN#" returns Command.FIN.
        if(FIN.toString().equals(commandName)){
            return FIN;
        }
        // if the name matches any of the remaining enums return whichever one matches
        else if(Arrays.asList(Command.values()).contains(Command.valueOf(commandName))){
            return Command.valueOf(commandName);
        }
        // if it still wasn't found, throw an exception
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("No enum defined for this string: " + commandName);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
            return name;
        }
    }
```

This code is tested and works.

You can use like:

```
Command k = Command.getEnum("#FIN#");
System.out.println(k.name() + "  " +k.toString());
k = Command.getEnum("PUT");
System.out.println(k.name() + "  " +k.toString());
```

And it's output would be:

```
FIN  #FIN#
PUT  PUT
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider creating a new (different name such as convert) static method in your enum classes.

```
public enum MyEnum{
      ....

     public static MyEnum convert(Object value){
       ...
     }
}
```